# SQL import not working to Drupal server thru Docker image

Tags: sql, docker, drupal

So I have a Docker image with database details for a Drupal server. I put all these details in my settings.php file and was able to connect to my Docker platform after dock-compose and docker exec.

However, when I try to import a local SQL file with drush sql-cli, I get the error:

Drush\Sql\SqlException: Unable to find a matching SQL Class. Drush[error]
cannot find your database connection details.

Assuming the SQL file is clean, are there any steps I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you tried including phpMyAdmin in your Docker setup? That could assist with the import - using the GUI to import...

As an alternative, I'd consider using [DDEV](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as the local dev environment setup, I find it helpful when it comes to dev environment-related issues.